# How to use mhchem in wordpress?

Tags: plugin-mathjax

I need to write chemical formulae in WordPress posts. For this I want to use mhchem package. I am open to use a plugin for that but there seems to be none in WordPress.org repository.

As mentioned [here](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html), mhchem extension can be enabled in mathjax configurations by adding following to the extensions array in the TeX block.

```
TeX: { extensions: ["mhchem.js"] }
```

I am able to load Mathjax on my server (using[Mathjax-Latex Plugin.](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mathjax-latex/)) Since Mathjax is available on my server, I hope mhchem package can be used through above mentioned tweak in Mathjax, but can't figure out where and how? I have asked for help on the [Mathjax-latex Plugin support forum](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-enable-mhchem-package-in-this-plugin/)  but got no response even after a year.

Any help in this regard is welcome. It would be fine for me no matter it is through [Mathjax-Latex Plugin.](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mathjax-latex/) or otherwise.

Comment: You should contact mathjax plugin support

Comment: This question is about how one can use mhchem in WordPress and NOT specific to Mathjax Latex Plugin. I mentioned this Plugin because I am using this to load Mathjax and there seems to be a solution for loading mhchem using Mathjax (as I have mentioned in my question). If you would have read my question till last I want to have mhchem with or without Mathjax. Does mentioning a Plugin makes a question non-WordPressy and thus off the topic?

Comment: I've re-read the question and I it does not give that impression, but your comment does clarify things. Edit your question so that it's clearer and more straight forward and I will reopen it

Comment: having investigated further and reading the code, I have come to my original conclusion, contacting plugin support would have revealed the `mathjax_config` filter which returns a PHP array that's then turned into JSON and passed directly to mathjax as the config object

Comment: https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/mathjax-latex/trunk/mathjax-latex.php#L173

Comment: something very similar to `add_filter( 'mathjax_config', function() { return ['Tex' => [ 'extensions'=> [ 'path/to/mchem.js'] ] ]; });`

Comment: I'd recommend switching to the Github version too, issues seem to get more attention there, https://github.com/phillord/mathjax-latex/issues

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect my requirement more clearly.

Comment: I've edited it and reopened, the mathjax package to me indicates mathjax.js, not the plugin, I've corrected that so that things are clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Mathjax plugin provides a filter named](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/mathjax-latex/trunk/mathjax-latex.php#L173) `mathjax_config` that can be used to add config parameters, something similar to this should do the trick:

```
add_filter( 'mathjax_config', function() {
    return ['Tex' => [ 'extensions'=> [ 'path/to/mchem.js'] ] ];
});
```

In the event you'd like to remove dependency on the plugin, you'll need to enqueue the mathjax library, whitelist all the relevant tags so they aren't

Comment: It works! Thank you very much for the help and for traversing extra miles to create an issue on [GitHub.](https://github.com/phillord/mathjax-latex/issues/22)